# Core Data and cumulative lightweight migrations

Tags: ios, core-data, core-data-migration

I have successfully versioned my core data model for a forthcoming version 1.1 of my app, using lightweight migration. I have a question about the maintainability of this approach.

If I again version my model in v1.2 of my app, and a user updates from v1.0 to 1.2, will the two migrations be applied successfully in sequence? That is, if I keep the versions of the model around, will the migrations be cumulative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If both migrations are lightweight then there's no need to apply both in sequence. Since [lightweight migrations can occur on](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmLightweightMigration.html):

- Simple addition of a new attribute
- Removal of an attribute
- A non-optional attribute becoming optional
- An optional attribute becoming non-optional, and defining a default
  value
- Renaming an entity or property

In the final case you supply the name used in the store (the 'canonical name'). That's the property name by default, so it ends up being whatever the property was called in the first version of your data model. You can then change the property name arbitrarily as long as you leave the canonical name alone.

So the net effect is that there's no sequence of events in which Core Data can figure out how to migrate from version 1 to version 2 and from version 2 to version 3 but not directly from version 1 to version 3.

Conversely, if you specify manual mappings via a mapping model then you'll either have to write code to apply all the manual mappings cumulatively or provide O(n^2) mappings as your data model advances.

Comment: I was nervous about the 'inference' part of lightweight migration - I can validate that core data is able to correctly infer the 1.0->1.1 mapping, and later the 1.1->1.2 mapping, but does that necessarily mean it will be able to infer the 1.0->1.2 mapping, if the mappings are not carried out sequentially? It seems that you are saying it always will be able to infer this correctly - just want to make sure.

Comment: My reading of the documentation is certainly that it should. Supposing your store is SQL what Apple is trying to tell you is that automatic migration can spot anything that's just adding or removing columns or tables (and will do those actions directly on the existing store). Renaming an entity doesn't change the column name if you preserve the canonical name and the other properties are just internal bookkeeping. So you can generally be confident where the difference between two versions would be just table and column addition or removal, were the backing store to be SQL.

Comment: If you remove a property in v1.1 then add it back in v1.2 core data wouldn't touch it from v1.0 -> v1.2 so you might have some unexpected data in there ;)